# Simple SQL Statement to Shrink Rows

Tags: sql

I have a simple table that is grouped by the `INTERVAL` column. Each `INTERVAL` has three corresponding rows, and each row has one value that corresponds to the average of some type of weight losses while the other types of weight losses are `NULL`. I would like to put all three types of weight losses into one row. Is there any simple way to achieve this?

Here is the original table that I have:

[image: Table]

Here is the table that I want it to look like:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
| INTERVAL | AVG los MANAGED | AVG los NPIC | AVG los UNMANAGED |
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
|1000-1249 | 54.627118644067 | 52.485833333 | 46.379746835443   |
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
|1250-1499 | 39.734567901234 | 36.705544933 | 33.1023622047244  |
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
| ...      | ...             | ...          | ...               |
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What dialect of SQL are you using? Please [edit] your question and add a tag for the specific database (e.g., MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, etc.) that you are using.

Comment: I don't believe that your original "table" is really table.  It looks like the result of a query -- and that query should be (and can easily be) fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
select `INTERVAL`, max(`AVG los MANAGED`), max(`AVG los NPIC`), max(`AVG los UNMANAGED`)
from your_table
group by `INTERVAL`
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Just aggregate by interval and take the max of each column:

```sql
SELECT
    "INTERVAL",
    MAX("AVG los MANAGED")   AS "MAX los MANAGED",
    MAX("AVG los NPIC")      AS "AVG los NPIC",
    MAX("AVG los UNMANAGED") AS "AVG los UNMANAGED"
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    "INTERVAL";
```